# Is there a non-circular explanation for computing the probability of the intersection of two dependent events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayesian

The explanation with which I'm familiar goes like this. Define the conditional probability P(A|B) as the probability of their intersections P(A and B) divided by the probability P(B). To figure out the probability of the intersection P(A and B) then, simply rearrange the terms of equation algebraically to obtain P(A and B) = P(A|B) X P(B).

The problem: What I'm struggling to understand is how to apply this equation in practice. It seems like whenever we want to figure out P(A and B), we need to figure out the values of P(A|B) and P(B).But to figure out the value of P(A|B), we already must figure out the value of P(A and B). So how is the equation P(A and B) = P(A|B) X P(B) helpful for figuring out the value of P(A and B)? In other words, to solve for it, we must figure out the value of P(A|B), which we can't do without knowing the value of P(A and B).

Comment: I think it's a very good question that shows you've been grappling with the material, as we all should. One comment is that sometimes $P(A|B)$ is given to us directly, as a modeling assumption. For example, we might be given that the probability of testing positive for a particular disease, given that you have the disease, is .99.

Comment: A simpler question: is there a non-circular explanation for computing the probability P(A)? Sure P(A) = 1 - P(not A), but P(not A) = 1 - P(A), so that's circular. So it seems we've already got a problem even before we get to more complicated stuff like P(A and B). **However,** if you know a way to compute P(A), maybe you can use the same method to compute P(A and B), i.e. just substitute (A and B) for A.

Comment: @littleO Thank you Prof O'Connor. I've been teaching myself some statistics and probability theory at my own pace. Sadly, the book seems to be geared for immediate application, when I'm more curious about reasons why some things are the way they are in this area of math.

Comment: @bof In the case of P(A), what would be intuitively non-circular explanation for me is as follows: Define the event A as a subset of the sample space. The probability of A then is the cardinality of A divided by the cardinality of the sample space.

Comment: @user51309 That definition of $P(A)$ only works if the sample space is finite and all outcomes are equally likely.

Comment: Why wouldn't the same work for P(A and B)?

Comment: @bof It would actually. Thank you for your patience. I'm a bit slow when it comes to math.

Comment: @user51309 Out of curiosity, which probability  textbook are you reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, a lot of time you can calculate $P(A|B)$ by assuming $B$ happened and see what is the probability of $A$. For example, let's say you draw 2 cards face down, then randomly choose 1 to flip up, and let $B$ is the event that exactly 1 red card and 1 blue card was drawn, and $A$ is the event that the flipped up card is blue. Then you know $P(A|B)$ without knowing $P(B)$ nor $P(A\bigcap B)$, because assuming you have 1 red card and 1 blue card faced down, randomly picking 1 of them to flip up give you blue card with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the occurrence of an event B is affected by the occurrence of another event A then we say that A and B are dependent events. So when the experiment is performed, it is known that event A has occurred. Does this affect the probability of B? This probability is the conditional probability. In principle you need to know both P(A and B) and P(B) to figure of P(A|B) (or P(A|B) and P(B) to find P(A and B)).

However, if the probability of B is unaffected by the prior occurrences of A, then we say that A and B are independent or that P(B|A)=P(B), which implies that P(A and B)= P(A)P(B).

Answer (score -1):

Or, … just compute $P(A\cap B)$ by whatever methods you may have at hand. Say, we are rolling a fair die and $A$ is "number is even" and $B$ is "number is prime", both having probability $\frac12$ - what could be more straightforward than to observe that "$A$ and $B$" means "number is $2$" and conclude that $P(A\cap B)=\frac16$?

There is nothing "inherent" that can avoid what you call circularity. In a way, working with  $P(A\mid B)$ (or $P(B\mid A)$) is just another way of expressing the fact that  $P(A\cap B)$ need not be the product of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite following you. The case with the die assumes that probabilities of outcomes of the trial are independent. In this case, from what I gather at least, one can simply multiply probabilities. But my question is for figuring out the probabilities of intersections of those events that are not independent.

Comment: @user51309 "prime" and "even" are certainly *not* Independent. After all $\frac12\cdot \frac12\ne\frac16$